# how to concatenate values of sublists stored in a list with another list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have two lists and want to merge them. At the moment I am using wo for loops but for sure there are more efficient ways and I do appreciate your help. These are my lists:

```
big_list=[[0.0, 4.0],[2.0, 5.0],[1.0, 1.0]]
small_list=[7.0, 9.0, 35.0]
```

both lists have the same lengths. In reality they are much more bigger. Then, I want concatenate the first sublist of the `big_list` with first value of `small_list`. Length of all sublists of `big_list` are the same and they are always `2`. Then I go for the next following sublists and values to have:

```
[[0.0, 4.0, 7.0],[2.0, 5.0, 9.0],[1.0, 1.0, 35.0]]
```

I tried the following code but I think there are faster and more efficient way to do it:

```
first_list=[]
for i in range (len(big_list)):
    arrange=[matches[i], seg_lines[i]]
    first_list.append(arrange)
final_list=[]
for i in first_list:
    new=[i[0][0], i[0][1], i[1]]
    final_list.append(new)
```

in advance, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One loop is enough for this

```
final_list = []
for i in range(len(big_list)):
    temp = big_list[i][::]
    temp.append(small_list[i])
    final_list.append(temp)
```

Or

```
>>> [big_list[i] + [small_list[i]] for i in range(len(big_list))]
[[0.0, 4.0, 7.0], [2.0, 5.0, 9.0], [1.0, 1.0, 35.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
big_list=[[0.0, 4.0],[2.0, 5.0],[1.0, 1.0]]
small_list=[7.0, 9.0, 35.0]

for i in range(len(big_list)):
    big_list[i].append(small_list[i])

assert big_list == [[0.0, 4.0, 7.0],[2.0, 5.0, 9.0],[1.0, 1.0, 35.0]]
```